# "Plushness" of a simple mechanical damper?

Tags: energy, momentum, everyday-life, collision, thought-experiment

What heuristics generally define the "plushness" of a mechanical damping or braking system? For example, if a person or some mass is to collide with a fixed wall or the ground (e.g., after a vertical fall), what heuristics describe how "plush" that impact would be (say, if we put some damping unit there)?

For example, a simple heuristic could be something like, "the plushest damper is the one that minimizes $\max\left|dE/dt\right|\,$" (i.e., creates the smallest instantaneous change in the object's kinetic energy, over the whole course of the collision). So, if we have to stop an object within some braking distance $d$, then the best damper would simply be a *constant-power* damper applying
$$P = -\frac{2Ev_0}{3d} = -\frac{mv_0^3}{3d}$$
throughout the whole collision (where $m$ is the object's mass and $v_0$ is the impact speed). The same is true for a damper having to stop an object within some braking time $T$, just applying a constant $P=-E/T$ against the object instead.

But, is this a *reasonable* heuristic? Would perhaps, a "smallest (instantaneous) change in momentum" heuristic instead be more appropriate? This would suggest a *constant-deceleration* damper would be best, simply applying a constant 
$$a = -\frac{3v_0^2}{2d} $$ over some desired braking distance $d$, or just $a=-v_0/T$ for a desired braking time $T$.

What are your thoughts on this? Perhaps, are my heuristics somewhat too oversimplified, or should be aiming for something else as far as what maximum "plushness" (or minimum collision feel) would really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the time derivative of acceleration (da/dt) is called the "jerk", and minimizing the "jerk" in a mechanical system minimizes the unpleasant sensations that humans feel when being tossed about in a vehicle like a car or train. So, your "plushness function" would furnish the conditions necessary for da/dt ~ (small as possible).

For this reason, train track curves are deliberately laid out according to a shape that makes the sideways accelerations that a passenger will sense upon the train's entering a turn *nondiscontinuous* (for lack of a better term), which then minimizes the "harshness" (which we define as 1/plushness) of the ride.

Comment: By da/dt "small as possible" do you mean close to zero (i.e., constant deceleration) or as negative as possible? Because the latter would imply I can make the initial deceleration a0 infinitely high to make da/dt infinitely negative. This would make for a very hard impact even if the jerk is very much negative during the "general" impact duration.

Comment: best case is da/dt = 0, at the start of the turn.

Comment: Ahh, so as close to "constant acceleration" as possible!

Comment: no, note the following: imagine entering a constant radius turn in a train. the instant you enter the curve, the da/dt term goes from zero to a constant IN AN INSTANT. da/dt is nonzero at that INSTANT- this means the acceleration is discontinuous RIGHT THERE and you get JERKED. the turn curve shape is set up so da/dt climbs SMOOTHLY from zero to its constant value in the main portion of the turn!

Comment: Ahh, good point -- I've ignored the initial acceleration! It seems then, in my damper case, if we are to set a maximum limit for $\max\left|da/dt\right|\le J$ and the initial deceleration $a_0=0$, then the "plushest" damper for some braking distance $d$ would then be a "constant-jerk" one, applying $$ J = -\frac{2v_0^3}{9d^2} $$ throughout the collision (where $v_0$ is the impact velocity). Does that look right then? And, for a desired braking time $T$, we'd simply have $J = -2v_0/T^2$

Comment: Whoa, I don't know- do you have access to a simulation program to try this out on?

Comment: No, not really -- I was just following off of the above jerk heuristic. If for plushness we set a maximum allowable jerk of $\left| da/dt\right|\le J$, then we may as well just let the damper always use the maximum $J$ (and so, use a constant jerk) to slow the object. I made a little mistake in the formula above (can't edit an earlier comment), so for a given braking distance $d$, this would actually amount to a constant-jerk damper applying a $$J=-\frac{8v_0^3}{9d^2}$$ throughout the whole collision. Likewise, for a desired braking time $T$, we'd have $J=−2v_0/T^2$

Comment: What's also interesting to note is that, if we also want to set $a=0$ at the *end* of the collision too (not just the start!), then for a given braking distance $d$, this would mean applying a constant $J = -v_0^3/d^2$ for the first half and $J=+v_0^3/d^2$ for the second half of the collision (time-wise!). Likewise, for a desired braking time $T$, we'd have $J=-4v_0/T^2$ during the first half, and $J=+4v_0/T^2$ on the second half. (For a simple one-way stopping damper, I figured we may as well have $a=0$ at the end too!)

Comment: So yes, in the latter case the jerk will switch instantaneously from some constant −J to a constant +J, but that should be fine, since we mostly just notice *changes in acceleration*, not necessarily changes in *jerk* too, that is!